# Can't re-authenticate Facebook session on Android

Tags: android, session, facebook-graph-api, authentication, single-sign-on

I have an Android app that uses the Facebook sdk, and I wish at some point to request Facebook credentials and re-authenticate the user.

However, if the Facebook app is installed, it seems that SSO is getting in the way of this. When I close the session and try to restart the activity, the user is already logged into Facebook.

I can use SUPPRESS_SSO with the Session.OpenRequest, which does force the user to re-authenticate, but my phone and emulator use a web view instead of the Facebook app when I do this, which is undesirable (is this normal?)

Is there a way to log out of Facebook "completely" so that even the FB app requires login? Or is there a way to re-authenticate the user with the FB app's login screen? Or am I just missing something?